# C# Set property of object while iterating on it in list

Tags: c#, properties, iteration

C# Won't allow me to do this.

```
foreach (Point point in filledPoints)
{
    point.X = 0;
}
```

filledPoints is a `List<Point>`
It gives me a compiler error: "filledPoints is a foreach iteration variable, so the associated members can't be edited" (Sorry, the message is in german and im bad at translating). But this works:

```
foreach (Point point in filledPoints)
{
    Point point2 = point;
    point2.X = point2.X / oldSize.Width * Size.Width;
}
```

Why does this not work and is there a more elegant way to bypass it?

Comment: The error message tells you exactly why it doesn't work.

Comment: It just tells me that it doesn't work but not why @Servy

Comment: I doubt that it tells you `That it doesn't work` also what line does it throw the error on..? do you know how to use the debugger..? if so set breakpoints and tell us the valid error

Comment: @MethodMan It is a compiler error

Comment: tell us what the compiler says exactly also edit the question and show how and where `filledPoints` is defined and what it's type is..

Comment: @KeineAhnung what version of Visual Studio/.NET/C# are you on?  I cannot find the version that has `" it doesn't work"` as an error message.

Comment: @MethodMan done

Comment: @maccettura I'm on .NET 4.6.1 and on Visual Studio Community 2017 (latest updates)

Comment: @KeineAhnung ignore me, I was being facetious.  To try and simiplify: the reason you are getting that error is because you are modifying the value inside a `foreach` (which you are not allowed to do).  Normally with reference types its ok to modify properties but `Point` is not a reference type, its a `struct`.  So when you are trying to modify a property, you are actually modifying the entire thing.

Comment: @maccettura Joeyrp already said that. That makes sense. Is there an alternative class or do I need to create it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because Point is not a reference type (it's a struct not a class). So the point variable in the foreach is not actually a reference to the original Point, it is a copy. The compiler doesn't let you modify it because (I assume) it would be easy to think you're changing the original when you are not.

I'm not sure if there's a better way but you could get around this by doing something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < filledPoints.Count; i++)
{
    Point temp = filledPoints[i];
    temp.X = 10;
    filledPoints[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Is there an alternative class or do I need to create it?

Comment: It's a bit messy but you could use a for loop and a temporary Point variable. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: @Joeyrp don't remove the code, its the right way of doing it.  I would hate for future readers to recreate the poor solution OP went with.  As for OP, you should really listen to peoples advice instead of dismissing it.

Answer (score 1):

@Cathal was close. You need to use a for loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
{
    //This copies the value of the point at the i index into a variable called point
    Point point = points[i];

    //Modifying the point.X property of the copy
    point.X = 0;

    //This replaces the point that is at the i index, with the new point that has the modified X property
    points[i] = point;
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2qJ5mE)

**EDIT**

I added some comments and additional code to my fiddle to illustrate why your foreach is not working the way you *think* it does.

Comment: That was the thing I've already dont with the foreach loop. Thank you but no more help is needed :D

Comment: @KeineAhnung I don't think your `foreach` loop will work the way you want it too.  You might want to re-look at my answer.

Comment: It works fine with a foreach loop. I just needed to create an own class to store these ints. The other thing was a struct and it gets copied if you store it. @maccettura

Comment: @KeineAhnung why would you write a new class?  You already have one that does what you need.  Just use the `for` loop like everyone is telling you to. If the struct does what you need then its _way_ faster to use that.

Comment: Why you dont understand? `Point` is a `struct`. If you make a new reference of a `struct` the `struct` will get copied. If you change an value of the first reference, it won't change on the second refernce.

Comment: A `struct` is a value type, so when you create a new variable it _copies_ the existing `struct` values.  Then you _modify_ it and re-add it to the list.  This is **exactly** what you need to do.  You should **not** be making a class that is 1 to 1 with `Point` because you do not understand `struct`.  I am trying to explain it to you but you are being stubborn.  **Look at the fiddle**.

Comment: @maccettura Okay, I give up. I will use your way

Comment: @KeineAhnung You are wrong.  The `for` loop solution that literally **everyone** has suggested is the simplest and most efficient way of doing this.  We are all trying to help you, but you have shown that you are too stubborn.

Comment: @KeineAhnung the answer you accepted it the right way too.  Just dont create your own class.  **Use the struct**

Comment: Ah sorry, but Joeyrp was first

Comment: @KeineAhnung **I do not want you to accept my answer**.  JoeyRp has the right answer too.  I just want you to understand what both of us are trying to say.  Neither of us want you to create a custom class, we both want you to use the struct and a for loop.

Comment: @macceturra I understand it now. Sorry!

Comment: @KeineAhnung It's ok, I just wanted to make sure you understood!  I'm here to help